# Passing multiple parameters through registry

Tags: c#, windows, parameters, registry

I have a program that I add into explorer's right click menu. When I run this on a single file or single folder it runs the program with the `%1` parameter as stated in the reg key `HKCR\*\shell\program\command\myprogram.exe %1` or `HKCR\folder` for files and folders respectively. This works fine, but the issue is when I select multiple files/folders, because it then executes that program for each of the selected. I know this is what should happen but I want to be able to handle multiple selections as if it was one, then foreach over the parameters. Is there any way I can do this? Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: do you need help on *passing the parameters into the application* __OR__ on *handling the parameters in the application*? Is it safe to assume the first?

Comment: Yeah its the first, I can handle the parameters when they have been passed to the application. The problem is when I select more than one file they each call the reg key, creating a separate instance of the program, I want to be able to just call it once. I would post the code I have but thats just handling the params passed. Tbh I think I might be going about it the wrong way which is why I need help, thanks.

Comment: hm, maybe you could write a batch file that passes all the file names into your app and put it in the context menu [like this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/multiple-commands-w-context-menu-registry-entry-t3867872.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the link but it still will only process the params given for each file selected, if I chose 3 files and right clicked the option it will still execute the program or batch file 3 times, thanks.

Comment: Its like it you zipped 3 files together, the compression program would zip everything selected into one file, not each file into its own compressed file, hope this explains it a bit better :)

Comment: It does, but unfortunately I don't know the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way to do it through registry.
Instead, you will have to create a shell extension.

Here's a good tutorial about shell extensions:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dateparser.aspx 
And here's a tutorial on writing shell extensions that handle multiple files:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide2.aspx 
I hope the combination of the two of them will help you create the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

After fighting this for days and not liking this solution, I found following works for me:

program "%1%2%3%4%5%6%7"

The quotes are what made it work.